# Aperture priority on Canon EOS 55 shows underexposured

Tags: canon, slr

I must be misunderstanding something here. I'm consistently reading an underexposure when I use aperture priority mode.

So here I'm in manual mode, f2.5, 1/20s and the camera says the exposure is fine.

[image: Manual mode]

And then if I set the camera to aperture priority mode with the same aperture of f2.5, it's opting for a 1/125s shutter speed and thus is showing as underexposed.

[image: Aperture priority]

Even setting the exposure compensation doesn't change it from showing as underexposed. I've experienced the same problem in bright sunlight where I had to set the shutter speed to 1/750s to get an OK exposure on manual.

In response to the comments I'm including a picture of the exposure compensation setting when on aperture priority mode

[image]

Can anyone advise me what the problem might be? This is quite a different beast to my DSLR so I'm feeling a bit lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scale on the bottom right of the LCD display is the exposure compensation scale. That's where the camera shows the current exposure compensation setting. Except in Manual mode, when the exposure compensation display is hijacked to be used to indicate how far your exposure settings deviate from the camera meter's recommended exposure.

So in "Av" mode, set exposure compensation to 0 and take note of the aperture and shutter speed values. Then switch to "M" mode and see what values result in the "needle" on the scale resting at 0. They should (will) be the same.